# Toolbar in a settings activity/fragment

Tags: java, android, android-preferences

I have searched the web for solution to my problem and can't seem to find anything that will work. I have implemented the following into my app and it does work. However, I would like to to add a toolbar at the top with the left arrow to allow the user to go back. can anyone help me out with this.

```
public class ActivitySettings extends PreferenceActivity {

     @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content, new MyPreferenceFragment()).commit();
     }

     public static class MyPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment {

          @Override
          public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
          }
     }
}
```

Thanks for any and all help.

Answer (score 1):

This is the exact use case of the [Preferences Support Library](https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/9kZ3SsXdT2T) - it allows you to **not** use `PreferenceActivity` and instead use a `PreferenceFragmentCompat`. This allows you to use `AppCompatActivity` and the `Toolbar` support built into it.

Answer (score 0):

The `PreferenceActivity` doesn't extend the `AppCompatActivity`.

As solution you can use the [PreferenceFragmentCompat](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html#v7-preference) with any `Activity` or `AppCompatActivity`

In this case you have to set `preferenceTheme` in your theme:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
  ...
  <item name="preferenceTheme">@style/PreferenceThemeOverlay</item>
</style>
```

In this way you can customize the `preferenceTheme` to style the layouts used for each preference.

Moreover with the new 22.1+ appcompat you can use the [AppCompatDelegate](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatDelegate.html) to extend AppCompat's support to any Activity.

You can check this official link to [AppCompatPreferenceActivity](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/Support7Demos/src/com/example/android/supportv7/app/AppCompatPreferenceActivity.java), where you can find an example of this technique.